# What are the best practices for appium framework using page opject model

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, appium

I am developing an automation framework for a mobile application using Appium (in java). I started with creating a class per view, in each class, I find and initialize elements of that class. Now after a while I understand my configuration for the framework is not correct and I'm not able to expand it. It would be great if anyone can introduce me an implemented framework on Github.

here is my config class, I use setdriver() to set a driver wherever I need.

```
public class Config {

public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> SetDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

    File appPath= new File("src");
    File app = new File(appPath,"My-debug.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "myDevice");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,app.getAbsolutePath());
    cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
    cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity","com.xxxx.xxxx.ui.launch.LaunchActivity");
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

    return driver;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** you have to create base class which load the driver.
**Note:** If you are using thread local, we can achieve the parallel execution without any issues

```
package com.vg.ui.utils.mobile;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Mobile {

    public static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driverThread = new ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver>();

    public void setDriver(String deviceName, String platformVersion)
            throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "Apps");
        File app = new File(appDir, "android-debug.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        if (deviceName.equals("Nexus6")) {
            driverThread.set(new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities));
        } else if (deviceName.equals("Nexus7")) {
            driverThread.set(new AndroidDriver(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub"), capabilities));
        } else if (deviceName.equals("Lenovo")) {
            driverThread.set(new AndroidDriver(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Check the device name and platformversion");
        }

    }

    public static AppiumDriver getDriver() {
        return driverThread.get();
    }

    public static void closeDriver() {
        if (!getDriver().equals(null)) {
             getDriver().quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Second**: Create a object class for the particular page using PageFactory methodology.

```
package com.vg.ui.pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class LandingPageObject {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@text='Account Create']")
    WebElement btn_accountCreate;

    public void click_AccountCreate(){
        /*driverUtil.clickandWait(btn_accountCreate);*/
        btn_accountCreate.click();
    }

}
```

**Third**: Then in your step definition class extend the Mobile driver class like below with the PageFactory of respective screens.

```
package com.vg.ui.stepdefinitions;


import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.vg.ui.pageobjects.LandingPageObject;
import com.vg.ui.utils.mobile.Mobile;

import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class LandingPage extends Mobile{

    LandingPageObject lp        = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), LandingPageObject.class);

    @When("^click on the button account create\\.$")
    public void click_on_the_button_account_create() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        lp.click_AccountCreate();
    }


}
```

Comment: Would you please explain more about PageFactory, how it works?

Comment: Please refer this links.  https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

First define your page as follow:

```
public class WelcomeScreen{
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "") //you can use id, accessibility-id or xpath
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "")
    private MobileElement element1;

    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "")
    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "")
    private MobileElement element2;

    AppiumDriver<MoblieElement> driver;
    public WelcomeScreen(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    public void clickElement2(){
        element2.click()
    }
}
```

Then setup the DesiredCapabilities and AppiumDriver.

After that use page object model in other class.

```
WelcomeScreen screen=new WelcomeScreen(driver);
screen.clickElement2();
```

> Make sure your **driver** is global.